# ubuntu 20.04: Failed to fetch openssl_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.11_arm64.deb 404 Not Found

Tags: apt, 20.04, docker, openssl, arm64

From docker for MacOS (M1 / arm64) I have updated to the latest ubuntu:20.04 docker image, and now my container fails to build as it does not find some specific package:

```
Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/o/openssl/openssl_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.11_arm64.deb  404  Not Found
```

And indeed, I've checked, the latest one is openssl_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.12_arm64.deb rather than 2.11.

How can this be fixed or at least worked around?
To whom should I report this issue?

Detailed log:

```
 > [linux/arm64  3/17] RUN apt-get install -y curl libcurl4 libcurl4-gnutls-dev &&     curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_17.x | bash - &&     apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends nodejs         psmisc         net-tools         vim         git         sudo         openssh-client         make         g++         openvpn         openvpn-systemd-resolved &&     npm install -g yarn &&     rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* &&     mkdir /v &&     echo OVPNFILE=/v/evpn/france_-_paris_-_1.ovpn > /v/current &&     echo AUTHFILE=/v/evpn/auth >> /v/current:
#0 0.074 Reading package lists...
#0 0.466 Building dependency tree...
#0 0.546 Reading state information...
#0 0.636 The following additional packages will be installed:
#0 0.636   ca-certificates krb5-locales libasn1-8-heimdal libbrotli1 libcurl3-gnutls
#0 0.636   libgssapi-krb5-2 libgssapi3-heimdal libhcrypto4-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal
#0 0.636   libheimntlm0-heimdal libhx509-5-heimdal libk5crypto3 libkeyutils1
#0 0.636   libkrb5-26-heimdal libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 libldap-2.4-2 libldap-common
#0 0.636   libnghttp2-14 libpsl5 libroken18-heimdal librtmp1 libsasl2-2
#0 0.637   libsasl2-modules libsasl2-modules-db libssh-4 libwind0-heimdal openssl
#0 0.637   publicsuffix
#0 0.637 Suggested packages:
#0 0.637   libcurl4-doc libgnutls28-dev libidn11-dev libkrb5-dev libldap2-dev
#0 0.637   librtmp-dev libssh2-1-dev pkg-config zlib1g-dev krb5-doc krb5-user
#0 0.637   libsasl2-modules-gssapi-mit | libsasl2-modules-gssapi-heimdal
#0 0.637   libsasl2-modules-ldap libsasl2-modules-otp libsasl2-modules-sql
#0 0.669 The following NEW packages will be installed:
#0 0.669   ca-certificates curl krb5-locales libasn1-8-heimdal libbrotli1
#0 0.669   libcurl3-gnutls libcurl4 libcurl4-gnutls-dev libgssapi-krb5-2
#0 0.669   libgssapi3-heimdal libhcrypto4-heimdal libheimbase1-heimdal
#0 0.669   libheimntlm0-heimdal libhx509-5-heimdal libk5crypto3 libkeyutils1
#0 0.669   libkrb5-26-heimdal libkrb5-3 libkrb5support0 libldap-2.4-2 libldap-common
#0 0.669   libnghttp2-14 libpsl5 libroken18-heimdal librtmp1 libsasl2-2
#0 0.669   libsasl2-modules libsasl2-modules-db libssh-4 libwind0-heimdal openssl
#0 0.669   publicsuffix
#0 0.734 0 upgraded, 32 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
#0 0.734 Need to get 3916 kB of archives.
#0 0.734 After this operation, 12.9 MB of additional disk space will be used.
#0 0.734 Err:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main arm64 openssl arm64 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.11
#0 0.734   404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
#0 0.785 Get:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main arm64 ca-certificates all 20210119~20.04.2 [145 kB]
#0 1.439 Get:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main arm64 krb5-locales all 1.17-6ubuntu4.1 [11.4 kB]
#0 1.752 Get:4 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main arm64 libkrb5support0 arm64 1.17-6ubuntu4.1 [30.4 kB]
#0 1.960 Get:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main arm64 libk5crypto3 arm64 1.17-6ubuntu4.1 [80.4 kB]
#0 2.366 Get:6 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/main arm64 libkeyutils1 arm64 1.6-6ubuntu1 [10.1 kB]
#0 2.505 Get:7 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main arm64 libkrb5-3 arm64 1.17-6ubuntu4.1 [312 kB]
#0 3.198 Get:8 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main arm64 libgssapi-krb5-2 arm64 1.17-6ubuntu4.1 [113 kB]
#0 3.576 Get:9 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/main arm64 libpsl5 arm64 0.21.0-1ubuntu1 [51.3 kB]
#0 3.959 Get:10 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/main arm64 publicsuffix all 20200303.0012-1 [111 kB]
#0 4.466 Get:11 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main arm64 libbrotli1 arm64 1.0.7-6ubuntu0.1 [257 kB]
#0 5.495 Get:12 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/main arm64 libroken18-heimdal arm64 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1 [39.4 kB]
#0 5.892 Get:13 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/main arm64 libasn1-8-heimdal arm64 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1 [150 kB]
#0 6.575 Get:14 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/main arm64 libheimbase1-heimdal arm64 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1 [27.9 kB]
#0 6.963 Get:15 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/main arm64 libhcrypto4-heimdal arm64 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1 [86.4 kB]
#0 7.435 Get:16 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/main arm64 libwind0-heimdal arm64 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1 [47.3 kB]
#0 7.699 Get:17 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/main arm64 libhx509-5-heimdal arm64 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1 [98.7 kB]
#0 8.240 Get:18 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/main arm64 libkrb5-26-heimdal arm64 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1 [191 kB]
#0 8.752 Get:19 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/main arm64 libheimntlm0-heimdal arm64 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1 [14.7 kB]
#0 9.050 Get:20 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/main arm64 libgssapi3-heimdal arm64 7.7.0+dfsg-1ubuntu1 [88.3 kB]
#0 9.532 Get:21 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main arm64 libsasl2-modules-db arm64 2.1.27+dfsg-2ubuntu0.1 [14.9 kB]
#0 9.684 Get:22 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main arm64 libsasl2-2 arm64 2.1.27+dfsg-2ubuntu0.1 [48.4 kB]
#0 10.12 Get:23 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main arm64 libldap-common all 2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.8 [16.6 kB]
#0 10.25 Get:24 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main arm64 libldap-2.4-2 arm64 2.4.49+dfsg-2ubuntu1.8 [145 kB]
#0 11.13 Get:25 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/main arm64 libnghttp2-14 arm64 1.40.0-1build1 [74.7 kB]
#0 11.54 Get:26 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal/main arm64 librtmp1 arm64 2.4+20151223.gitfa8646d.1-2build1 [53.3 kB]
#0 11.89 Get:27 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main arm64 libssh-4 arm64 0.9.3-2ubuntu2.2 [159 kB]
#0 12.56 Get:28 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main arm64 libcurl4 arm64 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.7 [214 kB]
#0 13.47 Get:29 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main arm64 curl arm64 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.7 [157 kB]
#0 14.46 Get:30 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main arm64 libcurl3-gnutls arm64 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.7 [213 kB]
#0 15.01 Get:31 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main arm64 libcurl4-gnutls-dev arm64 7.68.0-1ubuntu2.7 [307 kB]
#0 15.81 Get:32 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports focal-updates/main arm64 libsasl2-modules arm64 2.1.27+dfsg-2ubuntu0.1 [46.1 kB]
#0 16.02 Fetched 3317 kB in 15s (216 kB/s)
#0 16.02 E: Failed to fetch http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/pool/main/o/openssl/openssl_1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.11_arm64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
#0 16.02 E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

Comment: Have you updated your sources?  ie. `sudo apt update` to update the package lists your machine will work from?  `openssl | 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.12        | focal-updates   | source, amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x`  Did you ensure you don't get errors/warnings there?

Comment: yes, apt update was done at an earlier step.

Comment: ah but wait, I think this is the root cause:
```=> # W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Bad header line Bad header data [IP: 91.189.88.152 80]
 => => # W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
 => => # ## Installing packages required for setup: lsb-release gnupg...
 => => # + apt-get install -y lsb-release gnupg > /dev/null 2>&1```

Comment: I cleared docker's cache, restarted it, same thing. I really think something is wrong here.

Answer (score 2):

i solved same problem on ubuntu 20.04:

`sudo apt update`

`sudo apt upgrade`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I did a docker pull ubuntu:20.04 this morning again and... surprisingly it did pull some updated layers since yesterday evening!

Re-did a full build and now everything is working as expected... go figure!